# how to better organize your code in python?

Tags: python

I've been wonder how to clean up code to make my code easier and more readable for others reviewing my code. I'm fairly new to python, so I write everything into functions instead of using classes. Should I use more classes to better understand python more? I know that if the code works then it doesn't matter the way you did it but I just want to learn  how to decrease my lines of code.

```
def paymentData():
    calculateTotal = {}
    remainingAmount = []
    balance = int(raw_input('What is the balance of your bank account? \n'))
    amount = int(raw_input('What is the amount you would like to subtract? \n'))

    calculateTotal[balance]=amount

    total = balance - amount
    print('your total is: ' + str(total))

    remainingAmount.append(total)
    while True:
        choice = raw_input('To continue press "Enter" or type "q" to exit (For options type "o"). \n')
        if choice == '':
            clearScreen()
            paymentData()
            break
        elif choice.lower() == 'q':
            clearScreen()
            menuBudget()
            break
        elif choice.lower() == 'o':
            return calculateTotal, remainingAmount
            clearScreen()
            options_menu()
            break
        else:
            print('Invalid value.')
            continue
```

This is a function from one of my programs that is a budget program that takes the value `balance` that the user puts in and subtracts it from the `amount` value.

This function calls three different functions, one of them being `clearScreen()` that clears the terminal:

```
def clearScreen(numlines=100):
    if os.name == "posix":
        os.system('clear')
    elif os.name in ("nt", "dos", "ce"):
        os.system('CLS')
    else:
        print('\n' * numlines)
```

The `options_menu()` function that tells you the results of all the amount you put in (This is not completed nor do I plan to complete this project).

```
def options_menu():
    print('Do you want to see all of you total amounts?\n(Enter 1 for Yes, 2 for no.)')
    choice = int(raw_input())
    if choice == 1:
        time.sleep(3)

    elif choice == 2:
        menuBudget()
    else:
        print('Invalid Response.')

and the `menuBudget()` function that is the main menu for this script:
```

```
def menuBudget():                                                               # this is a menu for budget fast.
    menuRunning = True
    while menuRunning:
        print("""
        1. payment calculator.
        2. Comming Soon.
        3. Comming Soon.
        4. Exit/Quit.
        """)
        ans = input('Pick on the options above.\n')
        if ans == 1:
            clearScreen()
            paymentData()
            break
        elif ans == 2:
            print('Comming soon!')
            continue
        elif ans == 3:
            print('Comming soon!')
            continue
        elif ans == 4:
            break
        else:
            print('Unknown Option Seleted!')
            continue
```

Comment: This depends entirely on the code in question and what it does. Also note that lines of code isn't a good metric for anything. If you have complete working concrete code for us to look at, we can do so on Code Review, but this isn't appropriate for here.

Comment: python is not the issue here. You just need to apply the right software patterns to improve code reusability (including oop)

Comment: I am fairly new as well with no experience in production code styling but believe you develop your own style from learning and influences. I also believe if you include descriptive docstrings and comments you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `classes` means the use of OOP (**O**riented **O**bject **P**rogrammation). Sometimes your code will be very simple and doesn't need the use of classes. This paradigm depends of the type of project you want to build. 
If you use `imperative programmation`, the best practice is to use functions as you're doing. If you want to improve your code, here are some tips :

- Use meanful variable names
- Use meanful function names
- Sort your code into many files, feel free to have as much as you need. Try to call them once more with meanful names.
- Simplify your code as much as needed, and use python libraries functions (this comes with experience). For example, use the `max()` function instead for re-write other functions.
- Add comments to your code to make it re-usable even after month

Feel free to update this answer with other good-programmation pattern !